# Errors with authentication in a Modal using bootstrap and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, bootstrap-modal

I am utilizing react bootstrap and firebase to create a Modal to allow signIn - I have a create user component fully implemented but when I try to use a modal to handle my sign in it error out . Any help is much appreciated.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'event.target.elements' as it is undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import './Homepage.css';
import { Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


// Firebase Credentials
import app from '../firebase'
import { AuthContext } from '../Auth'

const Homepage = ({ history }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async (event)=> {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        history.push('/generate')
      }catch(error){
        alert(error);
      }
    },[history]
    );
    
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    if (currentUser) {
      return 
    }
    
    return (
        <div className='welcomeContainer'>
            <h1 className='welcomeBanner'>Resu.Me</h1>
            <h4 className='welcomeMessage'>
                Resu.me is the easiest solution for cover letters and resumes.
                <br></br> Simply input your credentials and contact information - We
                handle the rest!
            </h4>
            <Link className='genLeadButton' to='/generate'>
                <Button>Let's make a Resume</Button>
            </Link>

            <Button onClick={handleShow} className='loginButton'>
                Log In to Resu.me
            </Button>
            {/* <h2 className="servicesBanner">Score the job you deserve with the help of our tools</h2> */}

            <h2 className='servicesContainer serviceA'>PLACEHOLDER A</h2>
            <h2 className='servicesContainer serviceB'>PLACEHOLDER B</h2>
            <h2 className='servicesContainer serviceC'>PLACEHOLDER C</h2>



            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Login</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                
        <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
                            <Form.Label className='label'>Email Address</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name='email'
                                type='email'
                                placeholder="Login email"
                            />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <br></br>

                        <Form.Group controlId='formBasicPassword'>
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name='password'
                                type='password'
                                placeholder='Password'
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                </Form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant='secondary' type='submit' onClick={handleLogin}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
```

will map the value by the input id (`controlId` for react-bootstrap forms) in these two rows

```
<Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
<Form.Group controlId='formBasicPassword'>
```

---

so you have to make them identical like:

```
const { formBasicEmail, formBasicPassword } = event.target.elements;
```

or

```
<Form.Group controlId='email'>
<Form.Group controlId='password'>
```